# nginx not serving gzipped html for windows

Tags: nginx, gzip

I just don't understand why on windows browser nginx doesn't serve gzipped text/html, but it do serve gzipped css, js and other types..

```
http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 9;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the last line of your configuration doesn't turn the `text/html` type on, just remove the last line will be perfectly OK, or you can append text/html to the last line.

Comment: The isn't text/html is already dult, if i add text/html on the last line, nginx will give a warning that there is duplicate text/html value